# Checkboxes generated with ngFor array not updating when array changes

Tags: angular, checkbox

I have an array of items (itemsarray) that need to be represented by checkboxes. I have another array (addItem) that contains items that have already been checked.

Whenever addItem changes in the background due to a user selection, the checkboxes do not update. In addition, if an element is manually removed from addItem, the checkbox does not update.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-sm-12" for="secname">Choose Your Items</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10" *ngFor="let item of itemsarray; let i=index">
       <input type="checkbox" [checked]='additem.indexOf(item)>-1' (click)='checkditem($event,item)' >{{item.itemname.itemname}}
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you create one example in https://stackblitz.com

Answer (score 0):

I believe addItem.indexOf(item) returns -1 as it is comparing references.

Try creating a function to check (by property) if addItem array contains item object.

Ex.

```
itemChecked(item)
{
    const res = addItem.find(i => i.id === item.id);
     return res !== undefined;
}
```

And in your view:

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]='itemChecked(item)' (click)='checkditem($event,item)'>{{item.itemname.itemname}}
```